# Play video from one device to another

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I’m looking to essentially use two devices: raspberry pi 3 and Mac 10.15. I am using the pi to capture video from my web cam and I want to use my Mac to kind of extend to the pi so when I use cv2.videocapture I can capture that same video in preferably real-time or something close. I’m programming this using python on bout devices. I thought of putting it on a local server and retrieving it but I have no idea how I could use that with opencv. If someone could provide and explain a useful example, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. We are not a code-writing service. You will have better results if you take a stab at it yourself and then ask if you're doing something wrong. Do a little research; it will make people feel better about going to the trouble to help you out. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer a video stream, you could use instead of a custom solution a RTMP server on the source machine feeding it with the cam source and the target opens the stream and processes it.

A similar approach to mine is widely implemented into IP cameras: They run a RTMP server to make the stream available for phones and PC.